Invariance of log frobenius norm for the matrix
I am not sure whether it is true or not so any hint will be more helpful for me.
Prove that
$ \|\log(UAU')\|_F = \|\log(A)\|_F $
where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, $U'$ is its transpose, and $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

If we assume that the eigenvalues of $A-I$ lie within the unit circle then
$$
\log (U A U^\top) = \log (I + U(A-I)U^\top) = U (\log A) U^\top.
$$
